# How to get the particular document id? AngularFire 5.1.1 | Cloud Firestore | Documents

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire5

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemDoc = afs.doc<Item>('items/id');
    this.item = this.itemDoc.valueChanges();
}
```

Now, `this.item` has the value of a particular document except `id` of the document.

I want `id` and document data.

(Or)

If the `snapshotChanges()` is the way, how will I use this?

Thank you..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the document ID from [`valueChanges`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#valuechanges). As its name implies, it only exposes the value of the document, not its metadata.

To get the document ID, you will need to observe [`snapshotChanges`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#snapshotchanges) instead. Since the `snapshotChanges` exposes a [`DocumentChangeAction`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#the-documentchangeaction-type), you should be able to get the document ID from `this.itemDoc.payload.doc.id`.

Comment: Thank you Frank for valuable and quick response.
I don't know how to use snapshotChanges() for document.
Please suggest how to return document id with data.
-----
this.itemDoc = afs.doc<Item>('items/id');

this.item = this.itemDoc.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Item;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );

return this.item